# Aqua Data Studio import data can't read font

Tags: postgresql

i try to import data to postgres with aqua data studio but it can't read font how to solve this issue [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First verify if the import works correctly. Then open a Query Analyzer and execute a SELECT query on the table and see if you are able to view the records. The most likely reason you are not seeing the characters is that the font does not support the characters.  By changing the font configuration in ADS, you should then be able to see the characters. You can change this in File->Options->General->Appearance->Grid Results Font and/or ->Text Results Font.

If you use a Unicode capable font then you should be ok.

Comment: thank for reply, but i done it with Navicat tools And i think your solution can solve this issue, Thank